# Does Mill intend to identify attainment of desires and happiness?

Tags: utilitarianism, john-stuart-mill

Mill explcitly states that "in reality there is nothing desired except happiness", which I paraphrase as "if person X desires event Y, then X believes the attainment of event Y would cause happiness for X." Does he also intend to assert the converse?  "If X believes event Y would cause happiness for X, then X desires event Y."

Elsewhere it seems to me that Mill almost wants to outright *define* happiness as the attainment of desires, but I haven't seen him be explicit about a full equality statement.

Does Mill intend to identify attainment of desires and happiness?

Comment: the question is good, but it could use fleshing out if you are to claim your paraphrase

Comment: it could be that when i desire a good meal i believe it will make me happy, but in fact "the attainment of... [having a good meal doesn't] cause happiness"

Comment: @crazed a fair point.

Comment: Ironically the instant of time when attainment of a certain desire about something as an intentionality mark of the conscious mind is exactly the terminal steady-state of the rewarding happiness when it subsides. Thus the key is the *expected* or *estimated* belief of such future happiness the present lacks which truly defines happiness at the present in the time dimension in a sense while OTOH the present hasn't actually attained any such happiness yet. Thus this seems to suggest happiness if exists has barely anything to do with time at all...